# C# accessing class instance from method

Tags: c#, class, methods, scope

Seems like I'm struggling with a pretty basic problem right now, but I just can't find a good solution..

I have this code-snippet here:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BaseCharacterClass myChar = new BaseCharacterClass();
    }

    public void setLabels()
    {
        lbName.Text = myChar.CharacterName;
        lbHealthPoints.Text = (myChar.CharHPcurrent + "/" + myChar.CharHPmax);
        lbMagicPoints.Text = (myChar.CharHPcurrent + "/" + myChar.CharMPmax);
        lbClass.Text = myChar.CharacterClass;
    }
```

It says "myChar" does not exist in the current scope..

How do I fix that?

Comment: You'll have to declare the variable outside of your method.

Comment: Paste the code here. declare the variable on the top of `Form1` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to declare myChar outside of the constructor. You can define it on the class and then assign it on the constructor:

```
BaseCharacterClass myChar;

public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            myChar = new BaseCharacterClass();
        }

        public void setLabels()
        {
            lbName.Text = myChar.CharacterName;
            lbHealthPoints.Text = (myChar.CharHPcurrent + "/" + myChar.CharHPmax);
            lbMagicPoints.Text = (myChar.CharHPcurrent + "/" + myChar.CharMPmax);
            lbClass.Text = myChar.CharacterClass;
        }
```

Comment: Ow okay, great!

Comment: Done. :) May I be able to contact you somewhere else, because I got another question which includes rather more code.

Comment: Post it to Stack Overflow. It is the best way we can help.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt declare the variable as a class variable, only a local one. In `c#` the format is:

```
MyNamespace
{
    class MyClassName
    {
        //class wide variables go here
        int myVariable; //class wide variable

        public MyClassName() //this is the constructor
        {
            myVariable = 1; // assigns value to the class wide variable
        }

        private MyMethod()
        {
            int myTempVariable = 4; // method bound variable, only useable inside this method

            myVariable = 3 + myTempVariable; //myVariable is accessible to whole class, so can be manipulated
        }
    }
}
```

And so on. Your current constructor only declares a local variable within the constructor, not a class wide one